# How to make PHP makes this query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

As I am learning PHP, naturally, I decided to create a search feature on my webpage. However I wanted to make mine more unique, so rather than using just a simple html input field as the 'search' field, I created two html select tags which allow the user to select two options and search based upon that. I managed to get the php to generate the search query, however it wasn't the sql query I wanted. My php code managed to generate a query hat looked like this: `.com/results.php?option1=london&option2=car` whereas ideally I want it to generate something like this: `.com/results.php?combinedoptions=london+car` 
I've researched thoroughly into this and I hate to ask, what may be, a very simple question on this site.

> ```
>     $input = $_GET['input'];
>     $topic = $_GET['topic']; 
>     $location = $_GET['location'];
>     $combined = $input . $topic . '' . $location;
>     $terms = explode(" ", $combined);
>     $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";
> ```

```
    foreach ($terms as $each){
        $i++;
        if ($i == 1)
            $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%'";
        else
            $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%'";
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. AS this is a programming question site, you are strongly encouraged to post actual code, sample results and/or desired results, and so forth.

Comment: My apologies, I've added my code.

Comment: Are you having trouble getting the input from the form in the manner you would like? Or are you having trouble working with the input from the form on the server side? Also, what is the purpose of these 2 options? Can you give an example of user input and the expected result based on that input?

Answer (score 0):

You would just split the incoming string. Here's a piece of code:

```
<?php
    $combinedoptions = 'london+car';
    $array = explode("+", $combinedoptions);
    if (sizeof($array) != 2) { /*problem here*/ echo 'bad parameters'; return; }
    $option1 = $array[0];
    $option2 = $array[1];
?>
```

Just using the [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) method. [Compiled code.](https://ideone.com/VmCwOW)